# Power series of $\frac{sin(w+z)}{(1-z)(1-w)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a question that says to compute all terms of order up to 3 in the power series of the function 
\begin{equation}\frac{sin(w+z)}{(1-z)(1-w)}\end{equation}
At the origin.

I think what we would probably want to do is write the above function as

\begin{equation} \frac{\sin(z)\cos(w)}{(1-z)(1-w)}+\frac{\sin(w)\cos(z)}{(1-z)(1-w)}\end{equation}

And expand one variable at a time, but I dont exactly know how to do that.

If we just consider the first term and expand with respect to $z$, we get

\begin{equation} [z+z^2+\frac{5z^3}{6}+\frac{5z^4}{6}+...]\frac{\cos(w)}{(1-w)}\end{equation}

And then where would you go from here? Would you expand $w$ in a similar way and multiply? And what exactly does it mean by "all terms up to order 3" in a multi variable context? Thanks!

Comment: They look for$$f(0,0) + \nabla f(0,0)^T(w,z)^T + (w,z)A(w,z)^T,$$where $A$ is the (symmetric) matrix containing all the four second derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Comment: But this is not what we have covered in class. Can anyone help in a different way that might be a method of intro to complex analysis?

Comment: As in your post, consider only the first term. Now you can expand as follows: $$\frac{\sin(z)\cos(w)}{(1-z)(1-w)} = \frac{\sin(z)}{1-z}\cdot\frac{\cos(w)}{1-w} = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kw^k\right) = \sum_{n,k=0}^\infty a_nb_kz^nw^k.$$That could be what they want. But only upto order three. So, you can replace $\infty$ by $3$ above. You know how to retrieve the $a_n$ and $b_k$?